# Unable to parse data with BeautifulSoup: Python3

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

[Please click here to view the Tags][1]

The following is one of the tables of the website I am scraping. Here, under 'tbody' I wish to click on the 'MS' button tag under both odd and even class which provides me a different table for further parsing it.
I am using Selenium and Python 3 to perform Web scraping.
The current code only clicks on the 'MS' button in the first row. How can I create a for loop so that I can iterate through all the rows and click on 'MD' element in all the rows?

Thank you.

Following is the code:

```
table_0=table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
  for buttons in table_0.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
     buttons.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]')
     buttons.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="MS"]').click()
  for buttons in table_0.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
     buttons.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="even"]')
     buttons.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="MS"]').click()
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL? And please use the snippet tool available via [edit] to insert html so we can copy paste. And where is the MD text content element?

Comment: @QHarr The following is the URL: https://ibl.mdanderson.org/fasmic/#!/
I will edit the question so it will be easier to copy. Thanks

Comment: @QHarr yes, you can just input an alphabet say, 'A',  and from the drop-down you can select 'AKT1 (3 mutations)' . The go button doesn't work, so you will have to click enter or tab

Comment: Are you trying to click all the buttons in all 3 rows?

Comment: @QHarr No, only the button with the text 'MS' in all 3 rows as that provides me a table of gene information of my interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a CSS selector to gather those for clicking

```
.btn-group.btn-group-xs button:first-child
```

The selector certainly works:

[image]

Not sure whether you need waits but maybe something like:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn-group.btn-group-xs button:first-child")
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://ibl.mdanderson.org/fasmic/#!/")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='text']").send_keys("AKT1 (3 mutations)")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='text']").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn-group.btn-group-xs button:first-child")
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```

Comment: I don’t see any change when performing manually so not sure what change should happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This worked. I guess I was trying to implement using a logic based on the class.